# copy protect sqlite db file in windows phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have an existing sqlite db file(Windows phone 8) which I use only for reading tables (Not Inserting anything)
the sqlite file gets copied to ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder so db file are at both location.My problem is how to give security to the db file so that it should not be copied by any other user(hacker) or any application that access Local folder or Installation folder.
Is there any solution db file be copy protected without encrpting or any other simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if any other app can access that DB however you can always create a password protected SQLlite DB. [Take a look here for more info](http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/243727-Encrypted-SQLite-in-WP8).